# jQuery - Active / onclick / Repeat of code

Tags: jquery

I'm making my own website and I'm still a beginner with jQuery. But I've managed to do what I wanted. Everything is working, but I don't think it's efficient enough. There's duplication of code that doesn't make me happy, but I can't find a way to avoid this. Can you help ?

I'm just gonna provide the jQuery code since everything works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_content").load("home.html");

    $("#home").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $("#main_content").load("home.html");
    });
    $("#portfolio").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $("#main_content").load("portfolio.html");
    });
    $("#blog").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $("#main_content").load("blog.html");
    });
    $("#contact").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $("#main_content").load("contact.html");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than binding a `click` handler to each element based on an `id`, add a common class to every element and bind the `click` handler to that.

Then you can use

```js
$('#main_content').load(this.id + '.html');
```

to create the correct target

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_content").load("home.html");
    
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     
      $('#main_content').load(this.id + '.html');
      
      console.log('Loading:', this.id + '.html'); // demo
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" id="home">Home</div>
<div class="link" id="portfolio">Portfolio</div>
<div class="link" id="blog">Blog</div>
<div class="link" id="contact">Contact</div>
```

Comment: Get to know your native properties, use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')` @MaxBresil

Comment: Oh damn that's an embarrassing thing to forget about - thank you; I've made an edit

Comment: @Shiny ohh :) there's nothing to be embarrassed of, you used the jQuery way, I was just suggesting the JS way. There's not much performance gain - but it's not only shorter and simpler, but it also catches a developer interest over native JS stuff. -  It was mostly a comment for OP.